# Are measurable homomorphisms $ (\Bbb{C},+) \to (\Bbb{C},+) $ or $ (\Bbb{C},+) \to (\Bbb{C},*) $ continuous, and do they admit an explicit description?

Tags: topological-groups, continuity, measurable-functions

I am interested in generalizations of the following fact (known as **automatic continuity**, as pointed out below). I am especially looking for references to papers dating back to 1920’s. I feel that question like these have been well-studied when people were still interested in set-theoretic aspects of analysis...

> (**Cauchy**) Any measurable automorphism $ (\Bbb{R},+) \to (\Bbb{R},+) $ is necessarily a linear function, and any measurable homomorphism $ (\Bbb{R},+) \to (\Bbb{R}^{\times},\times) $ is necessarily an exponential function $ x \mapsto e^{a x} $.

Is something similar true for homomorphisms $ f: (\Bbb{C},+) \to (\Bbb{C},+) $ or $ f: (\Bbb{C},+) \to (\Bbb{C}^{\times},\times) $ (assuming that $ \ker(f) = \Bbb{Z} $ in the latter)? (Yes, see answers below.)

That is, I am interested in facts which follow the following rough pattern:

If a map is not set-theoretically wild, e.g. it is measurable or Borel, and satisfies some identities, then it is in fact continuous, and, furthermore, it can be given by an explicit formula.

Comment: topological groups tag is appropriate too.

Comment: "Measurable", with no qualification, means: inverse images of an open set is a Lebesgue measurable set.  Did I guess what you mean?

Answer (score 18):

The general phenomenon you're looking for is called *automatic continuity*. This is the line of research that stemmed from results regarding the continuity of homomorphisms from (**R**,+) to (**R**,+). The two principal general results illustrating the phenomenon of automatic continuity are the following.

**Theorem (S. Banach).** *Any Baire measurable homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous.*

**Theorem (A. Weil).** *Any Haar measurable homomorphism from a locally compact Polish group into a Polish group is continuous.*

Both of these theorems apply to the locally compact Polish group (**C**,+).

Automatic continuity is still an active area of research, see this [recent survey](http://www.math.uic.edu/~rosendal/PapersWebsite/AutomaticContinuity06.pdf) by Christian Rosendal.

Comment: I apologize for the significant overlap between your answer and mine. I hadn't seen your post until submitting my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the first theorem is due to Banach for Polish groups. Pettis generalized the result to a larger class of groups in his classic 1950 paper *On continuity and openness of homomorphisms in topological groups*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Theorem by Weil does solve my particular question about homomorphisms (C,+)-->(C,*). Although it would be nice to have a reference to the original paper, perhaps found in the book by Dales ot aumatic continuity. 

Comment: @mmm: I'm pretty sure Weil's theorem is in his 1940 book *L'intégration dans les groupes topologiques et ses applications*, Actualités Scientifiques et Industrielles, **869**, Paris: Hermann.

Answer (score 10):

On page 23 of his 1932 book [*Sur la théorie des opérations linéaires*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/kstresc.php?wyd=10&tom=1&jez=en) Banach proves:

**Theorem.** A Baire measurable homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous.

Note that Banach writes $+$ for the composition but neither does he assume nor use that a group is abelian. He proves the result first for Borel measurable homomorphisms and remarks immediately afterwards that the same argument even shows that a Baire measurable homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous, a fact usually attributed to Pettis for reasons that are unclear to me.

Recall that a topological group is *Polish* if its topology is second countable and metrizable with respect to a complete metric. The Baire $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Borel sets and the meager sets (beware that there are other uses of the term "Baire measurable" in the literature -- there are even published papers whose authors fell for this trap).

In particular, the specific question you ask about the real and complex numbers has a positive answer in all cases.

There is an entire industry, called *automatic continuity*, asking the question whether homomorphisms/derivations etc are continuous only due to their algebraic property. The easiest result in that direction states that a $*$-homomorphism between $C^{\ast}$-algebras is a linear contraction. One of the major players of that topic, H.G. Dales, has recently written a voluminous book of the same title, containing many results of that spirit and many historical remarks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially the reference to H.G.Dales, Banach algebras and automatic continuity, 2000. I shall look whether it has a reference to the particular question about homomorphisms (C,+)-->(C,*). 

Comment: mmm: Yes, that's the book. I'm not sure whether that specific question is addressed there. I doubt it.

Comment: To avoid confusion, instead of "Baire measurable" we can say "a map with the property of Baire".

Comment: As a further note, the theorem corresponds to Thm.4 on p.15 of the English translation published by North-Holland.

Answer (score 5):

I just thought that I should mention a result that considerably strengthens André Weil’s result mentioned by François in his answer above.

Adam Kleppner, in his 1989 paper [*Measurable Homomorphisms of Locally Compact Groups*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-106-02/S0002-9939-1989-0948154-8/S0002-9939-1989-0948154-8.pdf), proved that any Borel-measurable homomorphism between locally compact (Hausdorff) groups is continuous. It does not matter whether or not any one of the groups is Polish.