# Non-continuous representations of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

How does one construct a non-continuous representation $\rho:\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow G$ for some connected (finite dimensional) Lie group $G$?

Comment: You can embed $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ into $SL_2(\mathbf{C})$ and twist by a wild automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Right, good point!

Comment: For the existence of wild automorphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ and for the construction Misha quoted (due to Borel--Tits) you need the axiom of choice, however.

Comment: @Guntram: You are right of course, but if you eliminate the (uncountable) Axiom of Choice, then, at least in Solovay's model, all subsets of ${\mathbb R}$ are measurable and we are in the situation discussed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms (see pm's answer).  

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example can be found, for instance, in
[Boris Weisfeiler's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Weisfeiler) paper "Abstract homomorphisms of big subgroups of algebraic groups", pages 149-150, see

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/notre-dame-mathematical-lectures/Topics-in-the-Theory-of-Algebraic-Groups/chapter/Abstract-Homomorphisms-of-Big-Subgroups-of-Algebraic-Groups/ndml/1175197662)

His example of a discontinuous representation $\rho$ of $SO(n, {\mathbb R})$ to a semidirect product $H$ of $SO(n, {\mathbb R})$ with the abelian group ${\mathbb R}^N$ (the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$), works for $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ as well. Actually, Weisfeiler's example is even more dramatic: The image of the compact group $SO(n)$ under $\rho$ is *dense* in the noncompact Lie group $H$. Weisfeiler's paper also lists many positive results on rigidity of abstract homomorphisms of Lie groups.

Comment: Wow ! I would have bet that no such things could exist ! 

Comment: I had never heard of the volume containing that article.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are natural function spaces on Lie groups that are nevertheless not continuous (and, thus, are not representations in any usual, useful sense). For example, already on $G=\mathbb R$, the Fréchet space $V$ of all continuous functions, and/or the Fréchet space of bounded continuous functions, with the translation action of $G$, are not repn spaces, in the sense that $G\times V\rightarrow V$ is not continuous. The reason is the existence of not-uniformly-continuous continuous functions. For example, $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:

No measurable constructions are possible. Any measurable group homomorphism between locally compact groups is automatically continuous, in fact $C^\infty$ for Lie groups. You can have a look at the answers in an old question of mine:

[Are measurable automorphism of a locally compact group topological automorphisms?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms)

If I would like to find something non continuous, I personally would start with finding some non measurable automorphism of the circle first.