# Homomorphisms from circle to $GL(k,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups

Example 3 at the website [tricki](http://www.tricki.org/article/How_to_change_for_all_x_there_exists_y_into_there_exists_y_such_that_for_all_x) proves that every measurable homomorphism of groups from the circle to the non-zero complex numbers is continuous. Is there any analogous (true) statement for homomorphisms of the circle into $GL(k,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're taking the usual topologies on both the circle and the invertible k-times-k real matrices?

Comment: If so: IIRC, every measurable homomorphism between locally compact Hausdorff groups is automatically continuous, but I don't remember a precise reference. This has probably come up on MathOverflow before

Comment: See the answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms, which in turn refers to this paper https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-106-02/S0002-9939-1989-0948154-8/home.html

Comment: Thanks @GregoryArone - David should also note that in the discussions to that question, one also needs to consider a correction to the paper which you link to (same journal, 1991, pages 1199--1200)

Comment: This is actually rather elementary, see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442980/every-measurable-homomorphism-from-mathbbrn-to-mathbbc-is-exponenti).

Comment: Voted as duplicate of [Are measurable automorphism of a locally compact group topological automorphisms?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/), as it is answered [at this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/64140/14094), which yields something more general than both this question and the question there.